# sum of formatted numbers

Tags: visual-studio-2005, reporting, service

Regarding reporting services 2005:
I want to sum the field of a measure. If I sum 0.234 + 0.441 and format the sum to 2 digits after the point it will give 0.7. Because I format in the same way the field itself it shows 0.2+0.4=0.7.
It says I have to do the sum by adding the rounded field each time.
The only way I found to round a number to a few digits after the number is by format/FormatNumber and the reporting services doesn't accept format(sum(format(number))-is there another function?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve - is the problem that you're getting 0.7 rather than 0.67?  Or that you actually want to round the values, sum them, and round the result?

Answer (score 1):

The Math.Round function should do what you need, give it the number to round and no of decimal places you want (2 here I think), and returns a double (or decimal etc depending on what was passed in).

Then sum the rounded values.